# GetModuleFileNameW returns different path than GetCurrentDirectoryW (subst)

Tags: windows, winapi, path, getmodulefilename

I have created a subst drive like the following:

G:\ => F:\projects\projectname\

When I call GetModuleFileNameW

```
GetModuleFileNameW(GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), buffer2, MAX_PATH);
```

It returns the Module path using the original path, Ex:

```
F:\projects\projectname\projectname.exe
```

Despite me running the solution and project from the subst drive location.

However, if I make a call to GetCurrentDirectoryW

```
GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, buffer3);
```

It ends up returning the correct path, Ex:

```
G:\projectname.exe
```

How can I get GetModuleFileNameW to return the subst path rather than the original path?

Comment: this depended from which name for used in `CreateProcess` call - in your case `F:\projects\projectname\projectname.exe` form used. "How can I get .. " - impossible.

Comment: Reflects the very different layers in which these features are implemented.  SUBST and GetCurrentDirectory() are sub-system features, added to get MS-Dos compatibility.  A process goes all the way down the native OS.  Which doesn't know beans about SUBST so cannot know a remapping was in effect. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: SUBST simply create symbolic link. so all depended from how we run exe. if by name  `G:\projectname.exe` - we and got this name in `GetModuleFileNameW`, if by name `F:\projects\projectname\projectname.exe` - got this form. current directory independed from this. guess was call `CreateProcess("F:\projects\projectname\projectname.exe", ..., "G:\");`

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the answers but if what you say is true then I should never get a subst path from GetModuleFileNameW correct? 

But when I start my application from a different project, it returns the correct subst path.

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy - how you start projectname.exe ? GetModuleFileNameW return exactly path which used in createprocess

Comment: @RbMm Oh I see. I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying that GetModuleFileNameW can never return a subst drive but it can as long as CreateProcess called the process from that drive. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy - yes, GetModuleFileName return exactly path form which used in module load (exe start)